# GWT superdevmode on virtual machine server

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I am developing an app in GWT (currently version 2.8.0) and I am using our company's JS library, that only works on the Debian virtual machine, because there is a script running.

I used SDM before, but since we started using the JS library I have to launch the app on the VM. So I have to Compile the app (~30 sec) after any change and copy the compiled files to the VM.

Is there a way that I can tell the SDM to deploy app on the VM? Some flag like "-remoteserverip 192.168.56.101" or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: If you can launch SDM on VM, then "-bindAddress 0.0.0.0" CodeServer argument may help.

Comment: I don't think I can launch SDM on VM since it is just Debian running one script and I'm developing on Windows machine in Eclipse.